# How to have two outputs as an input for a function in Java

Tags: java

I'm creating a program in `Java` that reads a text file and displays the various outputs such as `total played` and `total won`.

Two out of the three outputs I have to display work perfectly which are the `total played` and `total won` but I can't get the last one to work, which is `return players` which takes `total played` and `total won` to produce the output.

What I have is:

```
List<Double> RP = data.RegexCheck(fileData.toString(), 
        "(Return Players: £) (totalPlayed/totalWon)*100",2);

//ReturnPlayers
double ReturnPlayers = 0;
for(double d : RP){
    ReturnPlayers+= d;
}
```

I got given the fact that `return players` is `(totalPlayed/totalWon)*100`. How would I go about doing this?

**Edit**

The way that I read the text file in was by

```
try(BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("myFile.txt"))){}
```

And the way that the outputs were written were by

```
System.out.println("The total times played is: " + totalPlayed);
System.out.println("The total times won is: " + totalWon);
System.out.println("Return Players value is: " + ReturnPlayers);
```

**Edit #2**

It is working, but the final output `RP` isn't displaying anything, only `0.0`, and I have a feeling that it should display a number as it takes in two outputs that do display numbers, `1240` and `320` respectively, and then multiplied by 100, which should give the display of `387.5`

**Edit #3**

An example of `myFile.txt` is

```
Start Game
Game number: 1
Player: lose
End Game
Start Game
Game number: 2
Player: lose
End Game
Start Game
Game number: 3
Player: lose
End Game
Start Game
Game number: 4
Player: won
End Game
Start Game
Game number: 5
Player: won
End Game
Start Game
Game number: 6
Player: lose
End Game
Start Game
Game number: 7
Player: won
End Game
Start Game
Game number: 8
Player: won
End Game
```

Comment: I get the impression that osme information is missing here.
What is `RegexCheck` doing and returning?
BTW: `RegexCheck` is not a method name according to the java conventions.

Comment: Can you show some more code? Where do you read the file, where do you write the output?

Comment: Why is it not working? Do you get an exception (and which one)?

Comment: @Janar I've edittied the question

Comment: Please try printing RP to the console - does the list contain the values?

Comment: @Janar I've tried printing RP to the console and it's still showing the original value

Comment: Can you post an example for the content of myFile.txt?

Comment: @F.Klein I've added an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java code

```
try(BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("myFile.txt"))){
    String line = null;
    int wonCounter = 0;
    int lostCounter = 0;

    while((line=br.readLine()) != null){
        if(line.contains("Player")){
            if(line.contains("won")){
                wonCounter++;
            }else{
                lostCounter++;
            }
        }
    }

    System.out.println("The total times played is: " + (wonCounter+lostCounter));
    System.out.println("The total times won is: " + wonCounter);
    System.out.println("Return Players value is: " + (wonCounter+lostCounter)*100.0/wonCounter);

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Output:

```
The total times played is: 8
The total times won is: 4
Return Players value is: 200.0
```